# mysql doesn't use index. help me figure out why

Tags: mysql, indexing

there is the table test :

```
show create table test;
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `body` longtext NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `handle_after` datetime NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `queue_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idxTimestampStatus` (`timestamp`,`status`),
  KEY `idxTimestampStatus2` (`status`,`timestamp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=80000 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

there is two select's

```
1) select * from test where status = 'in_queue' and timestamp > 1625721850;
2) select id from test where status = 'in_queue' and timestamp > 1625721850;
```

in the first select explain show me that no indexes are used
in the second select index idxTimestampStatus is used.

```
MariaDB [db]> explain select * from test where status = 'in_queue' and timestamp > 1625721850;
+------+-------------+-------+------+----------------------------------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                          | key  | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-------+------+----------------------------------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | test  | ALL  | idxTimestampStatus,idxTimestampStatus2 | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 80000    | Using where |
+------+-------------+-------+------+----------------------------------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+


MariaDB [db]> explain select id from test where status = 'in_queue' and timestamp > 1625721850;
+------+-------------+-------+------+----------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+-------+------+--------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                          | key                 | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra                    |
+------+-------------+-------+------+----------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+-------+------+--------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | test  | ref  | idxTimestampStatus,idxTimestampStatus2 | idxTimestampStatus2 | 302     | const |    4 | Using where; Using index |
+------+-------------+-------+------+----------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+-------+------+--------------------------+
```

Help me figure out what i'm doing wrong ?
How should i create index for first select?
why does the number of columns affect the index usage ?

Comment: please edit your question to show (as text, not images) output of `show create table test;` (this is much more useful than the original create commands) and `explain select restofyourselect;` for the two selects.

Comment: have you tried an index on (status, timestamp) instead of (timestamp, status)?  how many records are there in the table?  sometimes no index will be used because there aren't enough records to make it worthwhile

Comment: ok, the `test` table is my local table to reproduce the huge table in production.

Comment: How many rows are in there? If there are only nine rows (like indicated through `AUTO_INCREMENT=9`), a full table scan might be faster than using an index

Comment: in production there is > 3 000 000 rows, but behavior the same. in same `where` MySQL use fullscan if i want to get all columns, but use index if i want to get column id

Comment: And the `EXPLAIN` result looks the same as in your question (except for the number of rows)?

Comment: Do show the explain from production

Comment: ok, i added data to my question

Comment: Have you checked whether the indices on production are really the same as on your test system? Both queries don't use an index after all, and they do not list `idxTimestampStatus2`

Comment: Yes. I have checked. I doesnt added second index in production, it is added only in my test system. So, i gave two select with different order of condition to show that second index also doesn't work

Comment: The question is - why does the number of columns affect the index usage ?

Comment: Because the executor checks whether using an index is really needed. For 10 rows, it might be faster to scan all of them

Comment: why checker do so for 3 000 000 rows ? it would not bother me if this query did not fall into slow log

Comment: why when i change * to `id` in column list - this query  is processed many times faster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you saw is to be expected.  (The "number of columns" did not cause what you saw.)  Read all the points below; various combinations of them should address all the issues raised in both the Question and Comments.

Deciding between index and table scan:

- The Optimizer uses statistics to decide between using an index and doing a full table scan.
- If less than (about) 20% of the rows need to be fetched, the index will be used.  This involves bouncing back and forth between the index's BTree and the data's BTree.
- If more of the table is needed, then it is deemed more efficient to simply scan the table, ignoring any rows that don't match the `WHERE`.
- The "20%" is not a hard-and-fast number.

`SELECT id ... status ... timestamp;`

- In InnoDB, a secondary index implicitly includes the columns of the `PRIMARY KEY`.
- If *all* the columns mentioned in the query are in an index, then that index is "covering".  This means that all the work can be done in the index's BTree without touching the data's BTree.
- `Using index` == "covering".  (That is, `EXPLAIN` gives this clue.)
- "Covering" overrides the "20%" discussion.

`SELECT * ... status ... timestamp;`

- `SELECT *` needs to fetch all columns, so "covering" does not apply and the "20%" becomes relevant.
- If `1625721850` were a larger number, the `EXPLAIN` would switch from `ALL` to `Index`.

`idxTimestampStatus2` (`status`,`timestamp`)

- The order of the clauses in `WHERE` does *not* matter.
- The order of the columns in a "composite" index *is* important.  ("Composite" == multi-column)
- Put the `=` column(s) first, then one "range" (eg `>`) column.

More discussion: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql